# Integral including an Incomplete Gamma function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

Does anyone have an idea of solving following integral
$$ I =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\Gamma \left(a,b x\right)}{(x^2+1)}\,dx\,,$$
where $a,b>0$ are positive real values?

*Mathematica* gives an answer, but I do not know how it can be derived by using integral tables.

\begin{align}
I=&\frac{1}{{2 a (a+1)}}\biggl(\pi  (a+1) b^a \csc \left(\frac{\pi  a}{2}\right) \, _1F_2\left(\frac{a}{2};\frac{1}{2},\frac{a}{2}+1;-\frac{b^2}{4}\right) \\ &+a b \left((a+1) b \Gamma (a-2) \, _2F_3\left(1,1;2,\frac{3}{2}-\frac{a}{2},2-\frac{a}{2};-\frac{b^2}{4}\right)-\pi  b^a \sec \left(\frac{\pi  a}{2}\right) \, _1F_2\left(\frac{a}{2}+\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{a}{2}+\frac{3}{2};-\frac{b^2}{4}\right)\right)+2 \Gamma (a+2) (\psi ^{(0)}(a)-\log (b))\biggr)
\end{align}

**Eq. 2.10.1.3 in Integrals and Series [Vol 2 - Spl Functions] - A. Prudnikov** would be one of the closet answer, but I could not match parameters well.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $a$ is a positive integer and $b>0$, considering
$$I_a =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{x^2+1}\,\Gamma \left(a,b x\right)\,dx$$ there is only one which is simple
$$I_1=\frac{\pi}{2}   \sin (b)-(\text{Ci}(b) \cos (b)+\text{Si}(b) \sin (b))$$ where appear the since and cosine integral functions.

The problem is that, for $a>1$, it seems that the result can only be expressed in terms of the [Meijer G function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html).

The case of $a=2$ is

$$I_2=\frac {1}{\sqrt \pi}\,G_{1,3}^{3,1}\left(\frac{b^2}{4}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0,0,\frac{3}{2}
\end{array}
\right)$$

For $a>2$, we have

$$I_a=\frac {2^{a-2}}{\sqrt \pi}\, G_{2,4}^{4,1}\left(\frac{b^2}{4}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,1 \\
 0,0,\frac a 2,\frac{a+1}{2}
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

As written in comments, for rational values of $a$ we have quite nasty results. As an example, for $a=\frac 32$, the result given by a CAS is
$$2I_{\frac 32}=-\sqrt{\pi } \left(2 b^2 \,
   _2F_3\left(1,1;\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},2;-\frac{b^2}{4}\right)+\log (4b)+\gamma
   -2\right)+\pi ^{3/2} \left(C\left( \sqrt{\frac{2b}{\pi
   }}\right)-S\left( \sqrt{\frac{2b}{\pi }}\right)\right)+ \pi \sqrt{2b} 
    (\sin (b)-\cos (b))$$

Comment: In my case, $a$ is not an integer :( sorry I could not mention it in the original post! But this solution maybe helpful for some applications.

Comment: @Frey. If $a$ is a retional number, probably hypergeometric functions plus a bunch of terms.

Comment: If $a\geq 1$ is an integer, you can use $$
\Gamma (a,bx) = \Gamma (a)\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{a - 1} {\frac{{(bx)^k }}{{k!}}e^{ - bx} } 
$$ to obtain $$
 - \frac{{\Gamma (a)}}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{a - 1} {(k + 1)(ib)^k \left( {e^{ib} \Gamma ( - 1 - k,be^{\frac{\pi }{2}i} ) + ( - 1)^k e^{ - ib} \Gamma ( - 1 - k,be^{ - \frac{\pi }{2}i} )} \right)} 
$$ for the integral ($\Re b >0$).

Comment: @Gary. Thank you for this (and so many other things !). I used Meijer functions since it is the most compact writing. Have you any idea for any $a$ (this seems to be the question). I tried with rational values and obtained results (not pleasant at all). Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. Is it possible for you to share any results you got for any $a$?

Comment: @Frey. What do you mean by *share* ? Do  you want some numerical values (in this case, give me a value of $a$ and a range for $b$). Please, clarify. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. I thought you got some "I tried with rational values and obtained results (not pleasant at all)" :)

Comment: @Frey. Sorry ! I misunderstood. I shall put a few in the post.

Comment: I guess it should be a H - Fox function for any a. This is easily seen by the structure of the Meijer function

Comment: @stocha. Have you got any solution for any $a$? Can you please post?

Comment: 1. Transform $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ to MeijerG -> MeijerGReduce
2. Transform $\Gamma \left(a,b x\right)$ -> MeijerGReduce
3. Reduce the quadratic Argument of the two MeijerG Funktions with 
[Mathematical Functions Site](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/17/02/03/0004/)
4. Solve the Integral with [Mathematical Functions Site](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/21/02/03/01/)
H-Fox-Function for Mathematica on request.

Comment: @Frey: If you have problems with the derivation or you need the H-Fox-function for Mathematica, please let me know.

Comment: @stocha. I have written $1/(x^2+1)$ and $\Gamma(a,bx)$ by MeijerG and got the answer with H-Fox-function like $H_{3,2}^{1,3}(.)$. But I do not know how to implement it in MATLAB or Mathematica. There is no built-in function in software packages.

Comment: @Frey: I have an implementation of the H-Fox-Function in Mathematica, using Mellin–Barnes type integral and  by Meijer G functions ( a = k/l, l,k integer) moreover there is also another  version available in the community of wolfram, I did not test jet. I may send you my version, it is up to you. Therefore I need an email adress. Moreover I suggest you to read  [Mathai](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hans_Haubold/publication/266566090_The_H-function_Theory_and_Applications/links/00b4952b1bf090889c000000/The-H-function-Theory-and-Applications.pdf?origin=publication_detail)

Comment: @Frey: Mathai is a great reference for properties of H-Fox-Function, because it is not out of the question, that a reduction formula or other special cases exsists.

Comment: @stocha. The H-function I got has a form of $$H_{3,2}^{1,3}\left(\frac{1}{b^2} \left|
\begin{array}{c}
 (0,1),(-1,2),(-1-a,2) \\
 (0,1),(-2,2) \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$ where $a>0$ is not an integer and $b>0$. Can you please check whether your code works for this? Can you please post your code here? I do not think that we can share email here :(

Comment: @Frey.: Please take a look at my post - the last one on the side: [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2243766)

Comment: Is this the correct way to pass parameters to calculate above H function? $FoxH[\{\{\{0, 1\}, \{-1, 2\},\{-1 - a, 2\}\}, \{\{\} \}\}, \{\{\{0, 1\}\}, \{\{-2, 2\}\}\},1/b^2, ...,...,...]$. I did not get output :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122988/discussion-between-stocha-and-frey).

Comment: @Frey, did you received my emails, just to know?